# How to forbid grouping separator for h:inputText?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, locale, converters

I have an `h:inputText` with an `f:convertNumber` attached to it. Locale is set to `de`.

According to the locale, decimal separator is "," and grouping separator is "."

If a user will enter "72,5" the input is correctly interpreted as "72 and a half". But if I enter 72.5 the input is interpreted as 725.

This can lead to wrong input since there is no warning or error message if the user accidently hits "." instead of ",".

Is there a way to prevent this behavior without writing a custom validator or javascript? I think of using jsf standard converters or validators?

So far I tried `f:validateRegex` together with the `f:convertNumber` and `f:convertNumber` with a pattern but both didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion takes place before validation. So for your (custom) validator it's already too late. You need to create a custom converter and "validate" in there.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. So the easiest would be to write a custom converter that replaces "." with "," and then call jsf's standard numberConverter from within my custom one? Then both separators would be allowed as decimal separators. Alternatively I could fire a warning message if I detect "." and let the conversion fail.

Comment: Extend `NumberConverter` and call `super` when you're ready. As to the code logic, depends on the functional requirement which is not entirely clear. Do you want to silently convert or show error? What if the client **intentionally** used 1,000 to represent thousand and not one? It's complicated :)

Comment: Ok, showing an error message would be the safest, I think. It is a medical application storing drug dosages...